# How to add column to one dataframe from another in pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, nlp, tokenize

I'm new at pyspark and I was trying to do some tokenization on my data. 
I have my first dataframe:
**reviewID|text|stars**

I made a tokenization on "text" according to the pyspark documentation:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="text", outputCol="words")

countTokens = udf(lambda words: len(words), IntegerType())

tokenized = tokenizer.transform(df2)
tokenized.select("text", "words") \
    .withColumn("howmanywords", countTokens(col("words"))).show(truncate=False)
```

I got my tokens but now I would like to have transformed dataframe that looks like that:

**words|stars**

"Words" are my tokens.

So I need to join my first dataframe and tokenized dataframe to get something like that. 
Could you please help me? How can I add a column to the another dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it now. I just needed to make:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="text", outputCol="words")


tokenized = tokenizer.transform(df2)
tokenized.select("text", "words", "stars").show(truncate=False)
```

It works!